# How to configure multiple datasource in spring

Tags: spring

in my application i am trying to configure two database. After configured my application get deployed and successfully running with first database, but when ever i am try to access the second database i am getting "" this exception. Could any one help me... Thanks in advance.

My Configuration.xml file

```
 <bean id="propertyConfigurer"
class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
<property name="location" value="classpath:database.properties"></property>
```

```
<bean id="dataSource" class="com.iii.orn11j.common.dao.OrionDataSource" 
    destroy-method="close" >

     <property name="driverClassName" value="oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver" />
    <property name="url" value="${database.url}"></property>
    <property name="username" value="${database.username}"></property> 
    <property name="password" value="${database.password}"></property> 

    <property name="removeAbandoned" value="true" />
    <property name="removeAbandonedTimeout" value="60" />
    <property name="logAbandoned" value="false" />

    <property name="initialSize" value="2" />
    <property name="maxWait" value="30000" />
    <property name="maxActive" value="30" />
    <property name="minIdle" value="5" />
    <property name="maxIdle" value="15" />

    <!-- <property name="validationQuery" value="select 1 from dual" />
    <property name="testOnBorrow" value="true" />
    <property name="testWhileIdle" value="true" /> -->
</bean>

<bean id="dataSource2" class="com.iii.orn11j.common.dao.OrionDataSource" 
    destroy-method="close">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver" />
    <property name="url" value="${database.url2}"></property>
    <property name="username" value="${database.username2}"></property> 
    <property name="password" value="${database.password2}"></property> 

    <property name="removeAbandoned" value="true" />
    <property name="removeAbandonedTimeout" value="60" />
    <property name="logAbandoned" value="false" />

    <property name="initialSize" value="2" />
    <property name="maxWait" value="30000" />
    <property name="maxActive" value="30" />
    <property name="minIdle" value="5" />
    <property name="maxIdle" value="15" />
</bean>

<bean id="jdbcTemplate" class="org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"></property>
</bean>
```

And my Query method is:

```
@Autowired
OrionDataSource dataSource2;
@Override
public void testCon()throws Exception{
    JdbcTemplate temp=new JdbcTemplate(dataSource2);
    String qry="SELECT COUNT(*) FROM OM_ITEM";
    Integer count=(Integer)temp.queryForObject(qry, Integer.class);
    System.out.println("Connected 2nd DB -----> "+count);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

First you need to implement the `jdbcTemplate` with two dataSources and use those two `jdbcTemplate`. If you want to directly autowire the datasources then you have to use combination of `autowire` and `qualifier` or use just one annotation called `resource` as:

```
@Resource(name = "dataSource")
  private OrionDataSource dataSource;

@Resource(name = "dataSource2")
  private OrionDataSource dataSource2;
```

If you are trying to use two datasources then you need to inject two different jdbcTemplate.

```
<bean id="jdbcTemplate1" class="org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"></property>
</bean>

<bean id="jdbcTemplate2" class="org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource2"></property>
</bean>
```

If your query class instead you can inject the jdbcTemplate.

```
@Resource(name = "jdbcTemplate1")
      private JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate1;

@Resource(name = "jdbcTemplate2")
      private JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate2;

public void testCon()throws Exception{
    String qry="SELECT COUNT(*) FROM OM_ITEM";
    Integer count=(Integer)jdbcTemplate1.queryForObject(qry, Integer.class);
    System.out.println("Connected 2nd DB -----> "+count);
}
```

Comment: Thanks nebula, but still i am getting org.springframework.jdbc.CannotGetJdbcConnectionException: Could not get JDBC Connection; nested exception is org.apache.commons.dbcp.SQLNestedException: Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory (Io exception: The Network Adapter could not establish the connection) This Exception

Comment: That seems to be connection issue. Can you post full exception?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `@Qualifier` with `@Autowired` to inject specific bean:

```
@Autowired
@Qualifier("dataSource")
OrionDataSource dataSource;

@Autowired
@Qualifier("dataSource2")
OrionDataSource dataSource2;
```

Comment: Thanks Mithun, but still i am getting while access the dataSource2

Comment: org.springframework.jdbc.CannotGetJdbcConnectionException: Could not get JDBC Connection; nested exception is org.apache.commons.dbcp.SQLNestedException: Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory (Io exception: The Network Adapter could not establish the connection)

Comment: Looks like there is problem connecting to the database due to network issue. Could you please ping the server and check the database server ?

Comment: Also, please share the URL that you are using to connect to the database.

Comment: Hi mithun, There is no connection problem because i interchanged the db connection of dataSource1 to dataSource2, that time the same DB working fine. The actual problem is to which DB i am connecting with dataSource1 is working fine, the problem with dataSource2.

Comment: Share the URL for dataSource2.

Comment: <property name="url" value="jdbc:oracle:thin:@10.11.0.81:1521:ORCL" />

Comment: This is local dataBase server.

Comment: Since it is a local database server, could you please try using `localhost` instead of IP address.